# How to Set “cash on delivery” per store view magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to Set cash on delivery per store view Magento 2

Comment: please explain brefily

Comment: am using multiple stores I want cash on delivery only one store.... not for all store

Answer (score 0):

**How To Enabel Cash On Delivery Shipping Method :-**

> **Go To Stores -> Configration -> Sales -> Payment Methods -> Cash On**
>   **Delivery Payment -> Enable**

In Left Upper Left Corner You Can See **Store View Dropdown**

[image]

**Look This Image Based On Store View You Can Enable Payment Methods.**

Comment: Yes I did the same but here there is no Enable option Store View https://snipboard.io/kotG1h.jpg

Comment: like in Store A you want to enable cash on delivery method you can change store view A and Enable Cash On Delivery so COD Enable For Only Store A...

Comment: Yes but here there is no option... if I Enable Store View: Default Config it's applicable both store

Comment: default store means apply for both store

Comment: but i changed the Store View there is no option to enable http://snipboard.io/kotG1h.jpg